# Sending a PHP header to a html file upon server request?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

To follow new cookie legislation, we need to add a JS plugin to clients websites. However, one is proving difficult: pure HTML with a tonne of pages.

Is it possible in any way, shape or form to say:

```
server request {
    send a php file to inject into a html file sent from the server
}
```

Or anything vaguely similar?

Comment: I guess your translate application isn't working ok.

Comment: I like the "'amazing' cookie law tptb" ;-) whatever it is ...

Comment: @mahatmanich read [The 'amazing' cookie law](http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies.aspx)

Comment: tptb = "the powers that be" i.e. the government. @zomboble, please write questions in a formal, non-chatty way - questions and answers form a wiki, which we want to have as readable as possible.

Comment: So I assume you're looking for an answer where you don't have to edit any of the HTML, but want to inject something into the HTML somewhere?

Comment: Getting a CMS and building a template is probably quicker.

Comment: @halfer apologies, Leigh yes thats pretty much it, I have written a script in javascript however need it to appear everwhere, the client does not wish to migrate to a cms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way inject custom code into the HTML files without modifying them, is to add an additional layer of processing. It will slightly (probably unnoticeable) slow down each request, but it will certainly be less effort on your part.

Assuming you are using Apache, create an `.htaccess` file with a rewrite rule similar to the following (untested).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.html$ /injector.php
```

This will cause every request for an html file to be passed to `injector.php`

Inside this file, you can see the page that was originally requested using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Fetch this file from disk using a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) and locate the area you want to inject into using the built in methods (If you want to put a `<script>` in the `<head>` you probably only need [`getElementById`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)). Inject your code, and spit out the modified document.

FYI, it is perfectly allowed by the law to use cookies that are *necessary for operation*, this includes things like PHP session ids, and, a cookie to store any preferences related to cookie use. I repeat, it is fine to use a cookie to store the preference that a user does not want to use cookies.

In your `injector.php` you can detect the presence of such preference cookies, and based on that decide **not** to inject your javascript if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this looks by far the most promising answer for the problem. I will implement this shortly and see what result I get, in theory this should work. Thank you for your time, I will come back with a result and mark as correct answer if it is.

Comment: @zomboble I've had to deface a few clients sites with cookie law bullshit already. It's ridiculous, ruins user experience and client analytics for exactly zero gains. Don't feel pressured into making a site entirely cookieless, there are exceptions. Also, how is a pure HTML site generating cookies in the first place? Are you sure your client isn't trying to comply unnecessarily? No cookies = no problem.

Comment: Google analytics are present, they have put 4 cookies on the site

Answer (score 1):

You could also use js and a wrapper php file where your jquery plugin runs and just pull the html pages from file and feed them back to the body:

`$(body).empty().html(body-html-from-static-html-file);`

However you are going to do it, it is going to be hackky!

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to inject php into pure html. You can however do it the other way around ... write a php script that wrapps around your html and modifies that ... returning the html that you would want to ...

Comment: Hey, thank you for the comment; would this require editing all of the html files?

Comment: No you would parse the html via php, throw out what you want and go from there. Still it is an overkill. Getting an CMS building a template is probably quicker ...

Comment: I see thanks, will look into that. Using a cms would be a lot quicker and easier, however the client wishes not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the auto_prepend_file and auto_append_file php ini directives but php must be set to parse .html files for it to work on .html files. With output buffering you can capture the content and then modify the html. With auto_prepend_file php ini directive, reference a .php file that calls the function ob_start(); to start catching the output. Simply:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

Then you can with the auto_append_file php ini directive reference a file to modify the output. To get the output you would use ob_get_contents(); like so:

```
<?php $output = ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

Using some string functions in php you could modify the html which is stored in $output however you like. Then when you are ready to send $output, in the same file you appended use this:

```
<?php ob_end_clean(); echo $output; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal: use `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html$ /index.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and create `index.php` - assuming you have  in every file.

```
<?php
    if(file_exists($_GET['file'].'.html')){
        $file = file_get_contents($_GET['file'].'.html');
        $plugin = "<script> (function(){ /* your script */ }); </script>";
        echo str_replace('</body>', $plugin."</body>", $file);
    } else {
        echo "not found";    
    }
?>
```

Comment: Unnecessary to capture the portion before `html` and pass as a query string. The original request will be in the server variables. While your approach to injecting is simple, it just feels dirty to find/replace on html.

Comment: But it's more simpler for a website that is already old and needs something simple to modify.